# Android and custom URL scheme

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on an app with a custom url scheme.
It is opening some webpage for authentication in a chrome tab. This is done in xamarin forms like this:

```
Browser.OpenAsync(apiUrl + "mobile", new BrowserLaunchOptions
            {
                LaunchMode = BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred,
                TitleMode = BrowserTitleMode.Hide,
            });
```

everything work as expected if I return a webpage with a link and click the the link manually:

```
<a href="myscheme://myhost/myparameters">Click here to go the app</a>
```

But if i return a 302 redirect to the same url it will not close the chrome tab and dont focus the app again.
If i add a javascript in the response, it will not automatically open the url (close the chrome tab and focus the app)
I've tried things like this:

```
window.location = url;
window.open(url,'_self');
setTimeout(()=>window.open(url,'_self'),10);
```

(url is a valid variable, even tried alert(url) after changing the location and it show the correct url.

Why does it only work when I click the link manually?

Comment: So, it does not work in the emulator, but once I installed the app on a huawei p20 pro it works..

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain the user's security and experience, the browser prohibits the direct use of `window.open(URL)` in JS to open new links.

Try to change like below:

```
setTimeout(()=>window.open(url,'_self'),500); //The delay time must not be too short or you will be intercepted
```